# I can't decode this Base64 string

Tags: android, base64

I need help decoding this Base64 string

This is found in an game's save file it's in a `.xml` format. Here's the code

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <int name="autoplay" value="0" />
    <string name="&gt;@?OeK]?TI">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</string>
    <string name="5.1.5">990129cfbff38d6e7e15675a273d12a2</string>
</map>
```

The string I can't decode is `&gt;@?OeK]?TI`

Any ideas?

Comment: Show how you attempted to decode it? And maybe explain what you are expecting to see.

Comment: @weston I've tried using online decoders and the python base64 library to decode it, doesn't help :/ Ideally it would return me a string like... in human readable format

Comment: I don't think it contains a string. People often use Base64 to encode binary data before insertion into text formats like xml, json or urls.

Comment: @weston Ah okay. So how do i convert this into binary data?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Base64